# how to get the array output from a js function in java 8?

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, java-8, nashorn

I have the following method in the file test.js:

```
function avg(input, period) {
var output = []; 
if (input === undefined) {
      return output;
} 
var i,j=0;
 for (i = 0; i < input.length- period; i++) {
    var sum =0;
    for (j = 0; j < period; j++) {
        //print (i+j)
        sum =sum + input[i+j];
        }
    //print (sum + " -- " + sum/period)
    output[i]=sum/period;        
}

 return output;
 }
```

I want to pass an array from java to this function and to get the  js output array in java.
I used the following java code:

```
double[] srcC = new double[] { 1.141, 1.12, 1.331, 1.44, 1.751, 1.66, 1.971, 1.88, 1.191, 1.101 };

    try {
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");

        String location = "test.js";
        engine.eval("load(\"" + location + "\");");
        Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
        // double[] a = (double[]) invocable.invokeFunction("avg", srcC, 2);

        System.out.println("obj " + invocable.invokeFunction("avg", srcC, 2));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

I am able to see the output of the **avg js** function but I do not know how to get the **js output arrays from the js avg function in java**

Any support is appreciated.

Best Regards,
Aurelian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return type from `Invocable.invokeFunction` is implementation defined.  The Nashorn scripting engine returns an instance of an object that implements `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject`

This interface has a method `Collection<Object> values()`, so the only required changes are to cast the result of `invokeFunction` and then extract the collection of values:

```
 JSObject obj = (JSObject)invocable.invokeFunction("avg", srcC, 2);
 Collection result = obj.values();
 for (Object o : result) {
      System.out.println(o);
 }
```

output:

```
1.1305
1.2255
1.3855
1.5955
1.7054999999999998
1.8155000000000001
1.9255
1.5354999999999999
```

Comment: I just saw your answer. Is better then mine. thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your replies. The following code is better because uses the java 8 js engine instead of rhino from previous java versions:

```
    double[] output = {};
    try {
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");

        String locationTemp = "D:/test.js";
        engine.eval("load(\"" + locationTemp + "\");");
        Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;

        ScriptObjectMirror obj = (ScriptObjectMirror) invocable.invokeFunction("avg",
        input, period);

        Collection<Object> values = obj.values();
        if (values.size() == 0) {
            return output;
        }
        output = new double[values.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Iterator<Object> iterator = values.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Object value = iterator.next();
            if (value instanceof Double) {
                Double object = (Double) iterator.next();
                output[i] = object;
            }
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException | NoSuchMethodException | ScriptException ex) {
        log.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

Thanks **ninad** for his quickly answer

Best Regards, 
Aurelian,

Comment: You have Java 8 - no need to use an explicit interator, just use `for (Object value: values) { ... }` as I did in my answer.  Also, you forgot to increment `i` ... ;-)

Comment: indeed... i observed that i forgot the increment. Thanks again for your answer.